# Java concurrency with in-memory gzip creation and upload

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a Java ETL that queries Elasticsearch, packs the data into comma-delimited rows, appends the rows to a StringBuilder, compresses (gzip) the StringBuilder repeatedly as more rows are added until it reaches about 9.2 MB, then submits the compressed bytestream into the Salesforce Wave External Data API as a datapart until all parts are submitted and the transaction is completed (where it becomes data that can be visualized in SFDC Wave).

The challenge I am having is that since I refactored this code into a multi-threaded approach to make it faster, a problem has developed (it worked fine before multi-threading, albeit quite slow). In particular, the Wave Data Manager occasionally (not consistently) will encounter an unexpected EOF in one of the data parts submitted by this code.

I am showing the critical elements of my code below in order that someone with more concurrency experience can spot where my approach would allow a stray EOF to enter into the process...

The pertinent part of the thread executor is

```
long minMaxDelta = maxResultId - minResultId;
long theIncrementSize = minMaxDelta / ((long)iterations);

long threadIncrement = ((minMaxDelta) / threadSize) + 1;
long theCurrentMax = 0;
long theCurrentMin = minResultId;

for ( int ti= 0; ti < threadSize; ti++ ) {
    theCurrentMax = theCurrentMin + threadIncrement;
    Elk2WaveEtl etlThread = new Elk2WaveEtl(theCurrentMin,  theCurrentMax, 
        incrementSize,  targetDate,  elkPassword, parentID, 
        partnerConnection);
    new Thread(theGroup,etlThread, "elk2wave" + ti).start();
    logger.info("started thread for : " + theCurrentMin + " <= " + theCurrentMax);
     theCurrentMin = theCurrentMax;
}
```

So the number of threads started is an input parameter (threadSize), where each thread is given a range of Elasticsearch Ids to query for a given date.

As the data is retrieved from Elasticsearch within each thread, it's packed into pseudo CSV rows with this function call

```
StringBuilder theCsvFile = new StringBuilder();
theCsvFile.append(CSVUtils.makeStringLine(Arrays.asList(testId, 
    autobuildName, changelistOwner, scrumteam, testCategory, 
    bugNumber, depotPath, typeName, lastRunStatus, testOwner, devOwner,
    className, runningTime, isBenchmark, isFailure, changelist, 
    autobuildId, runId, changelistEmail, startDate, status, testName,
    failDate, testIdentifier, isFailure)));
```

Where the makeStringLine function is defined like this:

```
 public static String makeStringLine(List<String> values, char separators, char customQuote) throws IOException {

    boolean first = true;

    //default customQuote is empty

    if (separators == ' ') {
        separators = DEFAULT_SEPARATOR;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String value : values) {
        if (!first) {
            sb.append(separators);
        }
        if (customQuote == ' ') {
            sb.append(followCVSformat(value));
        } else {
            sb.append(customQuote).append(followCVSformat(value)).append(customQuote);
        }

        first = false;
    }
    sb.append("\n");
    logger.debug(sb.toString() );
    return sb.toString();


}
```

Now this is where the concurrency is relevant. As the compressed bytestream of data is submitted to the Wave External Data API, I have a synchronized code block so the various threads don't overlap each other here.

```
private static volatile AtomicInteger p = new AtomicInteger(0);

public int increment() {
    return p.incrementAndGet();
}

......

// write the test info to Wave when we have about 9MB of data
 if ( compressedLength >= 1024*1000*9 ) { // 9 MB 
    byte[] theData = compress(theCsvFile);
    theCsvFile = new StringBuilder();
    compressedLength = 0;

    if ( theData != null && theData.length > 0 ) {
        synchronized(p) {
        SObject isobj = new SObject();
        isobj.setType("InsightsExternalDataPart"); 
        isobj.setField("DataFile", theData);
        isobj.setField("InsightsExternalDataId", parentID);
        isobj.setField("PartNumber",increment()); //Part numbers should start at 1    
        logger.debug(" theRowSize " + theData.length);
        SaveResult[] iresults = partnerConnection.create(new SObject[] { isobj });
        for(SaveResult sv:iresults) {
            if(sv.isSuccess()) {
                String rowId = sv.getId();
                logger.info("saved rowId " + rowId + " for part " + pvalue());
            } else {
                com.sforce.soap.partner.Error[] es = sv.getErrors();
                for ( int w = 0; w < es.length; w++ ) {
                    logger.error(es[w].getMessage());
                }
            }
        } 
     }
  } 
 }
```

Where the compress function is defined:

```
public static byte[] compress(StringBuilder data) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.toString().length());
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
    gzip.write(data.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    gzip.close();
    byte[] compressed = bos.toByteArray();
    bos.close();
    return compressed;
}
```

Comment: I got this feedback from a colleague in my company:

From what I saw in your stackoverflow the problem is here:

if ( theData != null && theData.length > 0 ) {
synchronized(p) {

you are checking values
1) outside the synchronized block.
2) that doesn't appear to be volatile.
3) you could synchronize on "theData", and follow the doublyLocked idiom.


if (someValue == blah) {
synchronized(someValue) {
if (someValue == blah) { //is it still that value?
then do your work....
}
}
}

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your use of `theData`, as that’s a local variable pointing to a (purely local) temporary object. Well, we could be nitpicking and note that the `null`-test is obsolete as it is impossible for the array to be ever `null`, but that’s not related to your problem. I see that you have the condition `if ( compressedLength >= 1024*1000*9 ) `, but it’s not clear where `compressedLength` does come from. And it can’t be the compressed length, as you are going to compress *after* that check. And perhaps, the issue is that you have to process the last chunk, even if smaller…

Comment: Besides, it would make more sense to keep the output streams and repeatedly add the encoded content of the strings returned by `makeStringLine` until the threshold has been reached, instead of copying the strings to a `StringBuilder` and copying the `StringBuilder`’s content to a `String` again before encoding (within `compress`, you are calling `toString()` even twice, despite none of them is necessary).